# I would like to calculate a limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My problem is that I don't know how should I start solving it because of the 4-n. I'm almost stuck on this task for like an hour or more and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Here is the math problem I'm having

$$a_n = \left(\frac{5n+2}{6n-5}\right)^{n-4}$$

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\left(\frac{5n+2}{6n-5}\right)^{n-4}=\left(\frac{5n+2}{6n-5}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{5n+2}{6n-5}\right)^{-4}=\left(\frac{5+2/n}{6-5/n}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{5+2/n}{6-5/n}\right)^{-4}$$

Comment: I was wondering isn't it affecting the limit that the limit for the exponent is "heading" to minus infinite?

Comment: @Snayx It doesn't affect at all. Can you see what the first factor tends to? And the secon one?

Comment: At this point of time I don't but I try to work it out I've been a little bit amatuer or more like less educated in calculus and math in general.

Comment: @Snayx Can you determine the limit for $ \frac{5+2/n}{6-5/n}$?

Comment: @Snayx We have that $2/n \to 0$ and $5/n \to 0$ then $\frac{5+2/n}{6-5/n} \to \frac56$ and then $$\left(\frac{5+2/n}{6-5/n}\right)^{n} \sim \left(\frac56\right)^n$$

Comment: At the point of time I was sending out i realized.

Comment: @Snayx Well done! Bye

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=(\frac{5n+2}{6n-5})^{n-4}$ let $m_n=\frac{6n-5}{5n+2}$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}m_n=\frac{6}{5} \gt 1$ which means $\lim_{n\to \infty}(m_n)^n=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing:

$(5/6)^n\dfrac{(1+\frac{(2/5)}{n})^n}{(1-\frac{5/6}{n})^n}\cdot (\dfrac{6n-5}{5n+2})^4;$

0)Recall : $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+x/n)^n=e^x.$

1)$\lim_n (5/6)^n =0.$

2)Use (0) above

3)Third factor: The limit is $(6/5)^4.$